# Kali Linux and Bootloader problems

Tags: terminal, grub, bootloader, kali-linux, lilo

At first I was using Windows 8.1... I downloaded Kali and put it on flash memory. The options got me to either:

-Browse live
-Install

I browsed it live a little then went to installation.

### Grub Fails

Everything goes great till I get to retrieving files for GRUB. I wait and wait and in the end it says that it failed so I try again and same happens.

### Lilo fails

In installation I have the option to go back and choose Lilo bootloader but the same thing happens.

### Use no bootloader

Another option allows me to continue without a bootloader so after grub and lilo failing i choose to do that.

### Kali installed -- Useable now -- Can't be used again till a bootloader is here

I can now use kali as it is installed, but I can't restart because I simply have no bootloader to load it.

### Using Terminal

I chose terminal in Kali and decided to install grub with "sudo apt-get install grub". It goes on nice and no error happens at the end of this command.

### Grub not appearing

I restart the PC and I can only see a black screen with a white dash flashing... NO GRUB.

### Problem

I have kali installed, no bootloader works from flash memory of Kali...
Installing Grub from terminal continued normally, but still no sign of it
I have kali on a partition (only partition), but no bootloader

HELP: I need a way to have a bootloader on this PC to use Kali... What can I do at the state I'm in?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

I first used the standard "install" option, which you install via the command line. This didn't work and got problems with GRUB.

I quit the installation and booted up again and choose to install via the gui (press the down arrow to see more options, the live boot menu isn't very clear that there are more options).

The GRUB installed fine via the GUI installation.

Comment: Yes. Not it wont boot past grub into desktop environment